# Set filename from URL on Nginx with secure_link module enabled

Tags: nginx, arguments

I have the following secure_link config in my Nginx virtual host:

```
...

secure_link $arg_st,$arg_e;
secure_link_md5 SECRET$uri$remote_addr$arg_e;
...
```

Now the above works fine when the URL that is constructed by PHP script is like the following:

```
http://example.com/example_file?st=dzQUOtu5fLZTgBQtQkg8JA&e=1424446841
```

My issue is that I need to pass the file name as an argument too, so the URL should be in the lines of:

```
http://example.com/example_file?st=dzQUOtu5fLZTgBQtQkg8JA&e=1424446841&file=example.zip
```

but this returns 403.
Without the secure_link module I would normally go for

```
        if ($args ~* ^file=(.*)$)
    {
        set $filename $1;
        add_header Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=$filename";
    }
```

How should I edit my configuration in order to be able to download the file with the URL constructed including the file argument above?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
After fixing a typo in my code, I am now able to download the file without reaching a dead end at 403.
However, I can't get the file name to work.

**Edit 2: Fixed it**

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1 break;
add_header Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=$arg_file";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1 break;
add_header Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=$arg_file";
```

is the answer to the issue.